# Можно ли изменить функционал онлайн игры ( с закрытым кодом )?

Tags: разработка-игр

Пожалуйста, отнеситесь с пониманием. В данной теме ничего не знаю.

Допустим, у нас есть онлайн игра, я хочу добавить свой функционал, который будет отображаться исключительно на клиентской части, и никак взаимодействовать с сервером не будет - что то вроде чита.

В код игры я залезть не могу, потому что он скомпилирован, а декомпилировать не получится.

**Как же мне добавить этот функционал?**

В качестве доп функционала может быть замена текущих скинов на новые (очевидно, что на сервере они не хранятся).

*Понимаю, что полностью весь процесс вы, наверное, не опишите, но по крайней мере, я пойму в каком направление двигаться.*
*Спасибо.*

Comment: ищи какой-нибудь чат хацкеров в телеграме :) а тут надо задавать конкретные вопросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Если речь идет о замене графики, очевидно необходимо:

1. Выяснить в каких файлах и в каком формате хранятся скины на клиенте
2. Проверить возможность подмены этих файлов/данных на свои
3. Если речь идет о статической картинке, можно выводить свою картинку поверх окна игры;